# pygame group does not catch condition

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to write simple space-invaders-type game in python and pygame. And can't figure out why the the game does not catch condition..

So I have group of "enemies"

```
for row in range(90, 330, 40):
    for i in range(30, 460, 75):
        enemy = Enemy(i, row)
        enemies_group.add(enemy)
```

and I want them to move within the screen borders. So i wrote condition below. This condition is not triggered..

```
for e in enemies_group:
    if e.rect.left < 10 or e.rect.right > 590:
        for p in enemies_group:
            p.change_direction()
```

the thing is - if i decrease the number of enemies - it catches the condition (below)

```
for row in range(90, 330, 80): # increased step
    for i in range(30, 460, 75):
        enemy = Enemy(i, row)
        enemies_group.add(enemy)
```

Does Group has some limits? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

> ```py
> for e in enemies_group:
>    ...
>    for p in enemies_group:
>        ...
> ```

seems odd. This may lead to changing the direction several times. You do something for all enemies, but you do it for every enemy that meets the condition.

Actually you want to do something for all enemies, if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) enemy meets the condition. Therefore change to:

```py
if any(e for e in enemies_group if e.rect.left < 10 or e.rect.right > 590):
    for e in enemies_group:
        e.change_direction()
```